# continuous onto function from (0,1)x(0,1) to [0,1]x[0,1]

Tags: topology

How do I define such a function between the open unit square onto the closed unit square?
I cannot think of any definition for a function that will be surjective.

Comment: @Argyll I read it but it's still not very clear to me. A continuous function in this domain would preserve convergence. If I choose a sequence in the domain space,converging to any point in the boundary (that is not a point of the domain space), how does it proves the non existence of such a function? Such a sequence is not convergent in the domain. Then how can we use sequential continuity here?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Comment: @juaps_ You seem to be reading a deleted comment which I made when I saw 1-1 mistakenly. I've since written an onto only example. And as well, I just find out math mode doesn't work. Now I realized you asked a topology question on a programming stackexchange site. You should ask your future math questions in math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Argyll Yes,Yes. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map (0,1)x(0,1) to (0,2)x(0,2) by multiplying by 2 and then truncate everything outside (0,1)x(0,1) to its support.

Proving it is a matter of cycling through the lemmas and theorems you are allowed to use. For example,

- linear functions are continuous
- continuous in R2 metric space is topologically continuous
- constant functions are continuous
- restrictions of continuous function are continuous
- composition of continuous functions are continuous
- truncating is constant function and identity function respectively over two disjoint subsets; in other words, truncating is the composition of two [restrictions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology) of two respective continuous functions

You may find it easier to write out the truncation part using first principle.